# Authorization by phone number. The first request to enter a phone number

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

please help, maybe someone knows how to do this: Authorization by phone number. The first request to enter a phone number. Simulate sending a 4-digit authorization code (1-2 sec delay on the server). The second request to enter the code

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    def _create_user(self, phone, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given phone and password."""
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError('The given phone must be set')
        user = self.model(phone=phone, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, phone, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(phone, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, phone, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given phone and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(phone, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    phone = models.IntegerField(unique=True, verbose_name='Phone Number', blank=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.phone)
```